# Quick calculation of modulo with large exponent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In a correction of an exercise, the teacher simply wrote down

$$2^{107}\text{mod }187 = 161.$$

Is there any way for this to be so easily calculated?

Comment: Well, $187=11\times 17$ and it is easy enough to work out $2^{107}$ modulo each of those primes.  That's a good start.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$2^{10}=1024\equiv89\pmod{187}$$ $$89^2=7921\equiv67\pmod{187}$$ $$67^2=4489\equiv1\pmod{187}$$ so $$2^{107}=2^{100}\cdot2^{7}=(2^{10})^{10}\cdot128\equiv89^{10}\cdot128\equiv67^5\cdot128\equiv67\cdot128=161\pmod{187}$$as desired.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$2^{40}\equiv 1 \mod 187$$

Comment: Would you care to explain *how* to use that? It doesn'
t seem to have immediate connections to the question or the (known) answer.

Comment: it is the Little Theorem of Fermat

Comment: $2^{107}=2^{40\times 2}2^{27} \equiv 2^{27} \text{ mod}187$

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear enough: I wasn't asking about well-known theorems, I asked how to use your remark.

Comment: and what is your Problem?

Comment: when you got the $1$ you Can square the whole thing

Comment: I don't have a problem, I asked a question: how can your remark help to get to the known answer? If @Atmos can do $2^{27}$ by mental calculation, that's fine, but most can't.

Comment: hm, i have written the reason above, we use this trick very often!

Comment: Ok, I desist. When you understand something, you call it a device. When you don't, you call it a trick.